# Removing jScrollPane from a element

Tags: jquery, jscrollpane

how can I remove completely the jScrollPane from an element that it is applied?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you're using jScrollPane 1.2.3 (or similar) you can check this:
http://www.kelvinluck.com/assets/jquery/jScrollPane/remove.html

You need to call `jScrollPaneRemove()` on the container i.e. `$('.myownscrollpane').jScrollPaneRemove();`

This function isn't avail. on the latest version 2.x (http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/), reasons for it by Kelvin Luck (jScrollPane author) on [Google jScrollPane group](http://groups.google.com/group/jscrollpane/browse_thread/thread/7b1567b544568c1e/60f6d9507a0be539?lnk=gst&q=remove#60f6d9507a0be539).

I hope that will help a bit :)

Cheers

G.

Comment: And helps me very much. Thank a lot Gregory. :D

Answer (score 5):

For the current version v2.0.0beta11 - 2011-07-04.
You first need to retrieve the api. Then call the destroy method.

```
var element = $('. myownscrollpane').jScrollPane(); 
var api = element.data('jsp');
api.destroy();
```

Answer (score 0):

There is currently a fork of jScrollPane on github which has a destroy method added:

https://github.com/blackjid/jScrollPane/commit/d3cdee394f708a7bce5c0875f673bfc70484fa0b

I will be integrating this patch into the official jScrollPane release as soon as I have the time to bring it across and test it...